# Add custom textView and change text gravity in spinner

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

I have a custom spinner which I want to customize even more. Specifically, I want to have the text in that spinner display with a stroke and also make sure it's in the center of the spinner.

My custom spinner code looks like this for now:

```
public class MyCustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Typeface roboto;
    private Context ctx;
    private int fontSize = 22;


    public MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, int TextViewResId, String[] objects) {
        super(ctx, TextViewResId, objects);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        String locale = Locale.getDefault().toString();

        if (locale.equals("iw_IL") || locale.equals("he_IL")) {
            roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/yehudaclmboldwebfont.ttf");
        } else {
            roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/pacifico.ttf");
        }

    }

    public MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, int TextViewResId, String[] objects, int fontSize) {
        super(ctx, TextViewResId, objects);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        String locale = Locale.getDefault().toString();

        if (locale.equals("iw_IL") || locale.equals("he_IL")) {
            roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/yehudaclmboldwebfont.ttf");
        } else {
            roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/pacifico.ttf");
        }
        this.fontSize = fontSize;

    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(roboto);
        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.jenyBlue));
        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(fontSize);
        return v;
    }


    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(roboto);


        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: How do I use my custom TextView as the TextView in that spinner and how do I set the text of the spinner to be in the middle and not aligned left?

Comment: I see no "custom" TextView here.

Comment: Didn't think it should be included. The custom textView is working as it should but how do I implement it in the spinner? do I simply cast the spinner Textview as my own custom textView? I assume not because my custom textView extends the TextView class. So how do I go about it?

Comment: You will have to inflate a view containing your custom textview instead of calling super since that will use a textview.

Comment: Thanks to you I've managed to do it and solve my problem!